# How to port forward service?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I am using https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator and I have created a database cluster. The following services have been also created:

```
databaker-users-db          ClusterIP   10.245.227.1     <none>        5432/TCP   52d
databaker-users-db-config   ClusterIP   None             <none>        <none>     52d
databaker-users-db-repl     ClusterIP   10.245.156.119   <none>        5432/TCP   52d
```

I would like to forward the service to localhost and I tried as follows:

```
kubectl port-forward service/databaker-users-db 5432:5432
```

and it shows me:

```
error: cannot attach to *v1.Service: invalid service 'databaker-users-db': Service is defined without a selector
```

The content of the yml file

```
apiVersion: acid.zalan.do/v1
kind: postgresql
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: users
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: dev
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    team: databaker
  name: databaker-users-db
  namespace: dev
spec:
  databases:
    databaker_users_db: databaker
  numberOfInstances: 2
  postgresql:
    version: '12'
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 500Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 100Mi
  teamId: databaker
  users:
    databaker:
      - superuser
      - createdb
  volume:
    size: 2Gi
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 3):

It seems like, your k8s service `databaker-users-db` doesn't have `selector` specified.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: databaker-users-db
spec:
  ports:
  - ...
  - ...
  selector: <-- check here
```

> When a Service has no selector, the corresponding Endpoint object is not created automatically. You can manually map the Service to the network address and port where it's running, by [adding an Endpoint object manually](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors).

Comment: One more question. Can I connect to `databaker-users-db` through service or do I have to connect to Pod directly? For example, Would this be valid `jdbc:postgresql://databaker-users-db:5432/users`?

Comment: Yes, you can use service dns to connect pods. `<service-name>.<namespace>.svc:PORT` would be enough.